# Oracle query case statement in the where clause

Tags: oracle

I have a column field_name and column another name is data 
If the column name is Oracle and the Data coulmn is Null I don't want that returned in the query.

I tried this and it doesnt work

```
AND field_name = Case When field_name= 'Oracle' And Data IS Null
 field_name <> 'Oracle'
Else field_name
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this.

```
AND   1 = (
    CASE
        WHEN field_name = 'Oracle'
             AND   data IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is missing a `THEN` clause and the `field_name <> 'Oracle'` is invalid:

```
AND field_name = CASE
                 WHEN field_name = 'Oracle' AND Data IS NULL
                 THEN 'FALSE'
                 ELSE field_name
                 End
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
AND ( field_name <> 'Oracle' OR ( Data IS NOT NULL AND field_name IS NOT NULL ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a case statement, just this:

```
AND NOT (field_name = 'Oracle' AND data is null)
```

You could do it with a case statement, but it'd be a little weird. You want the first case to always evaluate to false, so you need the part after THEN to be something that cannot be equal to `field_name`. In this case, I added some letters ("not") to the beginning of the string, which can't be equal to the original string.

```
AND field_name = Case When field_name= 'Oracle' And Data IS Null
  THEN 'not' || field_name
  Else field_name
  End
```

Comment: The case when `field_name` is `NULL` must be handled separately. The solution you offered doesn't do that; it will let through rows where both `field_name` and `data` are `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that you can use.

```
    with tmp as ( 
    select 'Oracle' as field_name , 1 as data from dual union all
    select 'Oracle' as field_name , null as data from dual union all
    select NULL  as field_name , null as data from dual union all
    select 'Test' as field_name , null as data from dual )
    Select * from tmp
    Where 1 = case when field_name = 'Oracle' and data is null 
              then 0 
              else 1
              end
```

Comment: To the down-voter, Could you please explain the logic to down-vote? Down-voting without comment is not really productive I think.